# How could I call a data loader method from the ObservedObject ViewModel to show in the SwiftUI List?

Tags: swift, list, mvvm, dependency-injection, swiftui

Given this SwiftUI class which has a ViewModel object. The ViewModel class has a dependency which initialized by setDependencies() method. The ViewModel has an itemTypes array initialized with empty array, and a getAllItemType() method and a getAllItemTypeFromCoreData() private method. The getAllItemTypeFromCoreData() method fill the itemTypes array from the Core Data.

The ViewModel class:

```
class ItemTypeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: - Binding Properties
    @Published var itemTypes : [ItemType] = []

    // MARK: - Dependency Properties
    var coreDataStack : CoreDataStack!

    func setDependencies(with coreDataStack: CoreDataStack) {
        self.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
    }

    // MARK: - Logic functions
    func getAllItemType() {
        itemTypes = getAllItemTypeFromCoreData()
    }

    // MARK: - Database functions
    private func getAllItemTypeFromCoreData() -> [ItemType] { ...
        do { return try contextToUse.fetch(itemTypesRequest) }
        catch { return [] }
    }
}
```

SwiftUI class:

```
struct ItemTypeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack

    @ObservedObject var itemTypeViewModel = ItemTypeViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Items")) {
                ForEach(self.itemTypeViewModel.itemTypes) { itemType in
                    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(itemType.name!)
                    }
                }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
            .onMove(perform: move)
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                self.itemTypeViewModel.getAllItemType()    // CASE 1.
            })
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.itemTypeViewModel.setDependencies(with: self.coreDataStack)
            self.itemTypeViewModel.getAllItemType()    // CASE 2.
        })
    }


    private func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {...}

    private func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {...}
}

struct ItemTypeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {...}
```

In Case 1.:
The itemTypeViewModel.getAllItemTypeFromCoreData() called every time when a row inserted. I mean if the table has X element, then the onAppear called X times.
And its called every onMove and onDelete event. Therefore the onMove and onDelete events not work well.

In Case 2.:
The itemTypeViewModel.getAllItemTypeFromCoreData() called once on main thread, and then terminating with uncaught exception.:

> 2019-11-15 07:28:05.614884+0100 ItemApp[2123:75091] [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window. Table view: <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView: 0x7fb5d81b1c00; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 336}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <_TtGC7SwiftUIP13$7fff2c6b223419ListCoreCoordinatorGVS_20SystemListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxS2___: 0x7fb5d9476950>>
>   2019-11-15 07:28:05.624903+0100 ItemApp[2123:75091] *** Assertion failure in -[_TtC7SwiftUIP33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A4925UpdateCoalescingTableView _Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Rows_In_Section:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3900.12.15/UITableView.m:2406
>   2019-11-15 07:28:16.146859+0100 ItemApp[2123:75091] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (7 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

How could I solve this with keeping the getAllItemTypeFromCoreData() logic in ViewModel class?